# Probability function area vs Sum of Probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

I've a small confusion about Probabilities in Quantum Mechanics.

If a particle can move only on the positive $x-axis$ between $x=1$ and $x=\infty$, then its probability function must satisfy $\int_1^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$, right?

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is one such function. So, I think it's possible that the probability of finding a particle whose motion is restricted between $x=1$ and $x=\infty$ is described by this function.

Now, if we use this function, then the probability of finding the particle at $x=2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, then probability of finding it at $x=3$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. The probability of finding it at $x=4$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

So, the probability of finding the particle either at $x=1$, $x=2$ or $x=3$ is:

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=1.083333333333.....>1$$

How can it be greater than 1? Also, the probability of finding the particle at $x=1$ will be 1!. How is that possible?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty dx/x$ can be bounded from below by the rectangles $R_n$ which have x-spans $n < x < n+1,$ and y-spans $0 < y < 1/(n+1).$ The sum of their areas is $$\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18+\frac19+\dots$$ which can be further bounded from below by$$\frac12+\frac14+\frac14+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\dots,$$which can be rearranged into $\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\dots,$ which obviously trends to infinity. It needs an exponential number of terms to get to linearly higher values, which is why you hadn't noticed its divergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the statement "the probability of finding the particle at $x$".  This probability is actually $0$.  The function $f$ of your question is a probability *density*.  The product of this $f$ multiplied by a small interval $dx$, i.e. $f(x_0)dx$, gives you the probability of finding the particle in a bin of width $dx$ centered at $x_0$.

The correct understanding that $f(x)$ is a probability *density*, and recognizing that the probability at one specific point is $0$ is essential and a typical trick question on quantum mechanics exams.  The distinction is clear if you realize that, given $dx$ has unit of length and that $\int f(x)dx$ must be dimensionless since it's a probability, it must be that $f(x)$ has unit of inverse length.  Thus $f(x)$ at $x=1$ is equal to $1/m$ (i.e. $1$ per meter), not $1$.

In addition, it is the integral of $f(x)$ that must be one, not the function itself.  This does not prevent $f(x)$ itself from being greater than $1$ since what matters is the area under the curve.  In your setup, consider the function 
$$
\bar{f}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
2&\hbox{if } 1<x<3/2\, ,\\
0&\hbox{elsewhere}.\end{array}\right.
$$
This function takes the value $2$ over an interval of width $1/2$ and is $0$ elsewhere, so the area under the curve of this function is $1$, even if the function itself is greater than $1$ over a finite interval.  Of course it makes no sense to suggest that the probability at $x=1.25$ is $2$ simply because $\bar{f}(1.25)=2$.

As an analogy imagine a glass of water.  Asking how much water (in kg) is in a small volume $dV$ makes sense: this amount is just $\rho dV$, where $\rho$ is the mass density of the water.  Asking how much water (in kg) is *at one point* makes no sense - it is certainly not related to the density of water.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_1^b \frac{1}{x} dx=\ln(b)$ which does not equal 1, it diverges as $b \to \infty$.

Furthermore, the **probability density** of finding the particle at $a$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. So you cannot add the probability densities at $1,2,3,4...$ and expect to get 1. This sum (the **harmonic series**) also diverges - ie has no finite limiting value.

Answer (score 0):

1. "If a particle can move only on the positive x−axis between $x=1$ and $x=∞$, then its probability function must satisfy $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx=1$, right?"

It Should be "If a particle can move only on the positive x−axis between $x=1$ and $x=∞$, then its probability **density** function $f(x)$ must satisfy $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx=1$"

2. **Probability** can't be over 1, but not the case for **probability density** that can be over 1(must be positive). You pick $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ as the **probability density** function, however, it is not a real or meanningful one since it diverges as pointed by sammy.
3. Once you know the **probability density** function $f(x)$, then via the normalization formula $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=1$ to normalize it. The probability in the region $a<x<b$ can be obtained with $P(a<x<b)=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$